# Delphi XE10 Filtering database table using FORMAT LIKE

Tags: database, filter, format, filtering

I want filtering my database using fdtable. I write this code fdtable2.Filter := Format('PRODUK LIKE ''%s%%''', [edit1.Text]); but it was so sensitive with Uppercase and Lowercase. How can i write the code so when i write 'emon' in the edit.text, it filtering the word like 'Lemon' into the database. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the

```
fdtable2.Filtered := true;
```

in your Code?
You also have a mistake in your code!

```
fdtable2.Filter := Format('PRODUK LIKE ''%s%%''', [edit1.Text]);
```

This Code will Result in "PRODUK LIKE 'SOME_TEXT%%'"
you should set the s to the right Position to get it work properly.
This should work:

```
fdtable2.Filter := Format('PRODUK LIKE ''%%s%''', [edit1.Text]);
fdtable2.Filtered := true;
```

Comment: Yes, the code that you give is the same code like i used. But you right i should set the s to the right position. Thank brother